# Upgrading NodeMCU devkit from 0.9.6 to 1.5

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to upgrade a new NodeMCU devkit 1.0 which came with nodemcu-firmware 0.9.6, to a much newer build. I am using esptool on OS X 10.11.3, following the instructions from http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/flash/

I verified that I could connect to the NodeMCU and see the Lua prompt before beginning.

After "successfully" write the new flash:

```
kirsch$ ./esptool.py --port /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART write_flash 0x00000 nodemcu-dev-8-modules-2016-02-06-03-56-03-integer.bin 0x3fc000 esp_iot_sdk_v1/esp_iot_sdk_v1.4.0/bin/esp_init_data_default.bin 

Connecting...
Erasing flash...
Took 1.56s to erase flash block
Wrote 410624 bytes at 0x00000000 in 39.6 seconds (83.0 kbit/s)...
Erasing flash...
Took 0.09s to erase flash block 
Wrote 1024 bytes at 0x003fc000 in 0.1 seconds (85.4 kbit/s)...

Leaving...
```

However, if I reset the chip all I get from the chip at the dreaded (by me) 74880 baud is:

```
load 0x40100000, len 28292, room 16 
tail 4
chksum 0xef
load 0x33333333, len 858993459, room 4
```

I also tried placing `esp_init_data_default.bin` at address 0x7c000.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you see at 9600 baud?

Comment: At 9600 I see:~?�4�!��AO7E��Y�

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start esptool with a few more command line arguments to make sure it uses the correct SPI flash modes for your v2 devkit 1.0 ([confused about those names?](http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/)). The [v2 devkit uses](http://www.electrodragon.com/w/ESP8266_NodeMCU_Dev_Board#Flashing_firmware) SPI mode DIO, flash size 32mbit and SPI speed 40MHz. That translates to

```
kirsch$ ./esptool.py --port /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART write_flash -fm dio -fs 32m -ff 40m ...
```